# Does LAN data transfer compete with internet bandwidth and how to divide the bandwidth?

Tags: router, lan, bandwidth, switch, data-transfer

When I am transferring a large set of data to another server in LAN, does the upload of information to the router affects the internet speed of my computer? If it does, how do we categorise the bandwidth usage so that data transfer dose not affect internet usage (email, google, etc)? by IP address information , by application, etc?

The understanding I have is that even though during data transfer in LAN, you are not uploading/downloading from the internet(WAN), you are still using the same wires and hence you will affect the downloading/uploading speed of internet access?

How would you resolve this issue? Correct me if I am wrong, my understanding is that using switch you can transfer frames instead of packets in LAN without IP address. So can we devide bandwidth usages based on whether there is IP address attached to it? What are some other type of solutions?

I am a complete noob in the server internet field and tried to learn what is going on barely by googling and can't seem to find a very useful source on many of the questions I have. Any great source of information (including topology of network) would be really helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a network where you are currently experiencing a problem? What is in this network? Or is this a theoretical question?

Comment: this really depends entirely on how the network is architected.

Answer (score 0):

Traffic on a LAN does not pass through a router. LAN-to-LAN traffic is sent direct from host-to-host by the LAN protocol. Routers route traffic between networks, not on the same network.

Switches are transparent devices, and they do not strip off the frame in order to inspect the packet.

Your WAN use may be impacted because the traffic from a host to the WAN needs to traverse the LAN, and if the LAN is too busy, then frames may get dropped.

Normally, you control traffic on a LAN by topology and dividing it into VLANs, but there is not much in the way of control on a LAN.